# R plot linear fit subsetting

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression, prediction

My goal is to give a visualisation of different slopes of the same regression for three different groups. I have a regressor x and a regressand y. I have a group indicator which can take on three different values.

I would like to plot the three regression lines without displaying the scatter plot. Ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without providing any data or reproducible code, it is not easy to know what you want exactly. Does this help?

```
# Create some mock data:
n <- 100
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- rnorm(n, mean = x)
grp <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], replace = TRUE, size = n)

# Do linear regressions for each group
lin_regs <- lapply(unique(grp), function(g) lm(y ~ x, subset = g==grp))

# Plot lines
plot(x, y, type = "n")  # Initialize plot
for (i in seq_along(lin_regs)) {
   abline(lin_regs[[i]], col = i) # Plot each linear reg. with abline()
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you very much!